# Use PDF mediaId in Email Attachment

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

I am using the "api/_action/mail-template/send" action in a Shopware App to send an email to the customer and I want to add a document which was created before. If I understand it correct, I only have to give the mediaId as parameter to the request. The problem is, that the file can not be found ('detail' => 'File not found at path: media/29/50/18/1660063117/invoice_2544.pdf'),because the PDF files are in the files directory.

What am I doing wrong? Are PDFs a special case?

Thanks
Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are correct with your assumption. The primary keys you provide with `mediaIds` may only refer to files stored in the public filesystem. There's already a [feature flag in place](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e8ed81e0332a7dc628dc4b8f5115df3a593d282e/src/Core/Content/MailTemplate/Api/MailActionController.php#L51) that will allow to provide `documentIds` specifically instead, but since you're developing an app I doubt you'll be able to activate said feature flag for this purpose and the feature flag is only to be removed with the upcoming major release `6.5.0.0`.

What you can do however is provide raw binary data for your attachments with the request payload key `binAttachments`. You can find [how this data is handled in the `MailFactory` service](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/dea144715a735c2b6f53098b9c92f9eeebc16c21/src/Core/Content/Mail/Service/MailFactory.php#L62).

There's the endpoint `POST /api/_action/order/document/download` you can request with a payload `documentIds` that will give you the files binary content (You essentially download the file). You can provide multiple ids but it will merge all documents into one, so you might want to do one request per document if you want to keep the files separated as attachments.

You can then use the binary data you retrieved as `content` of your `binAttachments`.

PHP example with `GuzzleHttp\Client`:

```php
$response = $client->post($host . '/api/_action/order/document/download', [
    'json' => [
        'documentIds' => ['b0b3ac0ca218473babaffc7f0a800f36'],
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    ],
]);

$client->post($host . '/api/_action/mail-template/send', [
    'form_params' => [
        'recipients' => [
            'test1@example.com' => 'Test user 1',
        ],
        'salesChannelId' => '6923fd0d41e04521a2a259ba13f20bc3',
        'contentHtml' => 'officia Lorem non aute',
        'contentPlain' => 'eu veniam m',
        'subject' => 'sed adipisicing',
        'senderName' => 'enim occaecat aliquip veniam',
        'senderEmail' => 'test@example.com',
        'binAttachments' => [
            [
                'content' => $response->getBody()->getContents(),
                'fileName' => 'test.pdf',
                'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

While this is certainly a workaround, as of now this might be your best bet to achieve this purely with an app.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Unfortunately I already tried using this endpoint first "api/_action/document/documentId/documentDeepLink". But when I set the response to the content in the "binAttachments" property, I am getting this error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'content'. How do I convert the response?

Comment: Yes, you can't just set the response of a previous request as the value for `content`. You only want the body of the response for the downloaded document. That is a string and would be the binary data of the actual file, a file blob.

Comment: That is what I am already trying:
`"binAttachments" => [
      "content" => $document->getBody()->__toString(),
       "fileName" => 'file.pdf',
       "mimeType" => 'application/pdf'
 ]`

Comment: Ah, I see. The value to your key `binAttachments` has to be an array of objects, not just a single object. You can have multiple attachments for a single mail. If you're building the payload in php it should be `'binAttachments' => [ [ 'content' => '...', 'fileName' => '...', 'mimeType' => '...' ] ]`

Comment: @dneustadt I get the following error when I try to attach the file content:
`Failed sending mail to following recipients: {{ recipients }} with Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` I am using the $file->getContent() method. If I base64 encode it and then attach it, the mail goes through but when I open the attachment in the email it shows a corrupt file. I can confirm that this error only happes when adding the file in the binAttachments array. If there are no attachments, the email goes through. Any help in there?

Comment: Have the exact same problem in SW 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who traps in the same problem... it seems to be a bug in shopware that will be hopefully fixed soon.

https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-28169